# how to properly read and modify a file using python

Tags: python, string, text, file-io

I'm trying to remove all (non-space) whitespace characters from a file and replace all spaces with commas. Here is my current code:

```
def file_get_contents(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    return f.read()

content = file_get_contents('file.txt')
content = content.split
content = str(content).replace(' ',',')
with open ('file.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

when this is run, it replaces the contents of the file with:

```
<built-in,method,split,of,str,object,at,0x100894200>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue you have is that you're assigning the method `content.split` to content, rather than calling it and assigning its return value. If you print out `content` after that assignment, it will be: `<built-in method split of str object at 0x100894200>` which is not what you want. Fix it by adding parentheses, to make it a call of the method, rather than just a reference to it:

```
content = content.split()
```

I think you might still have an issue after fixing that through. `str.split` returns a list, which you're then tuning back into a string using `str` (before trying to substitute commas for spaces). That's going to give you square brackets and quotation marks, which you probably don't want, and you'll get a bunch of extra commas. Instead, I suggest using the `str.join` method like this:

```
content = ",".join(content) # joins all members of the list with commas
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want though. Using `split` is going to replace all the newlines in the file, so you're going to end up with a single line with many, many words separated by commas.

Comment: the content was all integer values to be used in an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you split the content, you forgot to call the function. Also once you split, its an array so you should loop to replace things.

```
def file_get_contents(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    return f.read()

content = file_get_contents('file.txt')
content = content.split() <- HERE
content = [c.replace(' ',',') for c in content]
content = "".join(content)
with open ('file.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

Comment: After the `split` there aren't going to be any spaces left, so the `replace` calls are fairly pointless.

Comment: good point. just following the code from the answer. I assume that the intent might be to do some actual replacement.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to replace characters i think you would be better off using python's re module for regular expressions.  sample code would be as follows:

```
import re

def file_get_contents(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    return f.read()

if __name__=='__main__':
    content = file_get_contents('file.txt')
    # First replace any spaces with commas, then remove any other whitespace
    new_content = re.sub('\s', '', re.sub(' ', ',', content))
    with open ('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
      f.write(new_content)
```

its more succinct then trying to split all the time and gives you a little bit more flexibility.  just also be careful with how large of a file you are opening and reading with your code - you may want to consider using a line iterator or something instead of reading all the file contents at once